# How can use Outlet for layout with React Router Dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a project on React, and for layout, I am using an old version. I want to use the new version of `react-router-dom` but I have some problems. These are my codes.

App.js

```
<Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
  <Route element={<LoginPage />} path="/login" />
  <Route element={<RegisterPage />} path="/register" />
  <Route element={<ForgotPassword />} path="/forgotPassword" />
  <Route element={<Verify />} path="/forgotpassword/verify" />
</Route>
```

But `AuthLayout` is old coding. And it works.

```
const AuthLayout = ({ page, children, img }) => {
  return (
    <main className={`auth-layout ${page}`}>
      {children}
      <div className="images">
        <img src={img} alt={page} />
        <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" className="logo" />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};
```

I want to use `Outlet` and `useOutletContext`, but I don't know how I can send `page` and `img` props? I don't get this topic very correctly.

One of my child props - `ForgotPassword`

```
import ForgotImg from "assets/img/forgot-password.svg";

<AuthLayout page="forgot-password" img={ForgotImg}>
  <form onClick={sendPassword}>

  </form>
</AuthLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you are asking for how routed children/nested routes can pass up a `page` and `img` value to the parent layout route that it can then render.

You could do this with a layout route with some state and callbacks that are passed down via a Context provider, and a wrapper component that accesses the context and passes the values up.

Example:

```
const AuthLayout = () => {
  const [{ img, page }, setState] = React.useState({});

  const setPageData = React.useCallback(
    ({ img, page }) => setState({ img, page }),
    []
  );
  
  return (
    <main className={`auth-layout ${page}`}>
      <Outlet context={{ setPageData }} />
      <div className="images">
        <img src={img} alt={page} />
        <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" className="logo" />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

const withPageData = (Component, { img, page }) => (props) => {
  const { setPageData } = useOutletContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    setPageData({ img, page });
  }, [img, page, setPageData]);

  return <Component {...props} />;
}
```

```
import ForgotImg from "assets/img/forgot-password.svg";

...

const ForgotPassword = (props) => {
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <form onClick={sendPassword}>

    </form>
    ...
  );
};

const pageData = { page: "forgot-password", img: ForgotImg };

export default withPageData(ForgotPassword, pageData);
```

```
<Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
  <Route element={<LoginPage />} path="/login" />
  <Route element={<RegisterPage />} path="/register" />
  <Route element={<ForgotPassword />} path="/forgotPassword" />
  <Route element={<Verify />} path="/forgotpassword/verify" />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear the AuthLayout wrapper from your child component:

```
import ForgotImg from "assets/img/forgot-password.svg";
  <form onClick={sendPassword}>

  </form>
```

Add Outlet instead of {children}

```
import {Outlet} from "react-router-dom"  

const AuthLayout = ({ page, children, img }) => {
return (
<main className={`auth-layout ${page}`}>
  <Outlet />
  <div className="images">
    <img src={img} alt={page} />
    <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" className="logo" />
  </div>
</main>`  
);
};`
```

I guess you do not need to use useOutletContext hook if you are not passing any props from AuthLayout to its children.